# Is there a PY terminal in Vscode that prints only the result without showing the file paths?

Tags: terminal

I'm just starting in Py, and I had difficulties in finding the result of the code, is there some configuration or terminal in which only the result comes out without showing the path of the folder "C:\Useres...."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlucV.png)

I downloaded the Code Runner extension from VS, but I don't know if I set it up right, or if it's just like that.